# Vectorizing Eigen::Matrix

Tags: eigen

I would like to create "vectorized" high-performant Eigen::Matrix for running multiple simulation scenarios at once, where matrix scalar elements would 
be vectors of doubles instead of doubles, with componentwise operations defined for these vectors. ArrayXd looks like a good choice for such scalar element,
having component-wise operations already defined. Being a relative novice with Eigen, I have some questions in this regard.

1. Is it true that when multiplying two matrices of the type Matrix< ArrayXd,...>, generally speaking, no unnecessary temporaries are created 
   during the computation of the sum of products of ArrayXd elements, due to lazily evaluated expression templates for ArrayXd?
   Given that in our case, there is no interaction between "horizontal" 2-dimensional slices of Matrix< ArrayXd,...>, is it the most efficient data representation 
   in terms of the computing speed, or may be Tensor module would be better?
2. What are the possible approaches for managing heap memory allocation when creating large Matrix< ArrayXd,...> matrices?
3. Product of two Matrix< ArrayXd,...> does not compile due to several overloads for operator*, giving the error message below.

Is there an easy way to fix it?

```
error C2666: 'Eigen::MatrixBase< Derived>::operator *' : 3 overloads have similar conversions
with [ Derived=Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> ]           

...\vendor\i686-win32-vc12.0\include\eigen\src\core\generalproduct.h(387): could be 'const Eigen::Product< Derived,Derived,0> 
Eigen::MatrixBase< Derived>::operator *< Derived>(const Eigen::MatrixBase< Derived> &) const'
with [ Derived=Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> ]           

...\vendor\i686-win32-vc12.0\include\eigen\src\plugins\commoncwisebinaryops.h(50): or 
'const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp< Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op< Eigen::Array< double,-1,1,0,-1,1>,PromotedType>,const Derived,
const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp< Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op< Eigen::Array< double,-1,1,0,-1,1>>,const Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>>> 
Eigen::MatrixBase< Derived>::operator *< Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>>(const T &) const'
with [PromotedType=Eigen::Array< double,-1,1,0,-1,1>, Derived=Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>, T=Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>]           

...\vendor\i686-win32-vc12.0\include\eigen\src\plugins\commoncwisebinaryops.h(50): or       
'const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp< Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op< Eigen::Array< double,-1,1,0,-1,1>,PromotedType>,
const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp< Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op< Eigen::Array< double,-1,1,0,-1,1>>,const Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>>,
const Derived> Eigen::operator *< Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>>(const T &,const Eigen::MatrixBase< Derived> &)'
with [PromotedType=Eigen::Array< double,-1,1,0,-1,1>,Derived=Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,T=Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>]           

while trying to match the argument list '(Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>, Eigen::Matrix< Eigen::ArrayXd,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>)'
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're wasting your time: 1) `Matrix<ArrayXd>` is pretty bad regarding memory and 2) matrix-matrix or matrix-vector products are highly optimized for float and double scalar type, and it will run much slower with ArrayXd as scalar type. What about simply letting Eigen does its job on SIMD vectorization, and on your side leverage multi-threading by processing simulations in parallel using OpenMP?

Comment: @ggael. Thanks for your answer, it will save me time and effort. One more question, if possible. From what I saw online, Eigen 3-dimensional Tensor 
might work for my purposes. Probably, it will not have problems with heap allocation, like Matrix< ArrayXd,...>. But I did not see "product" 
operator defined for Tensor, just component-wise operations. Is "product" going to be added to Tensor any time soon? Is Tensor as efficient as Eigen::Matrix
speed-wise? Appreciate your help.

Comment: The closest to products is contractions. It might be enough for your needs.

Comment: @ggael. If I have two 3-dimensional Eigen tensors A and B, which can be viewed as collections of vertically stacked matrices, to multiply these matrices in Python
we can do:  

               numpy.einsum("ijk,jlk->ilk", A, B)                  
    
where output (after ->) index "k" means that, although index "k" occurs twice before ->, there is no summation over "k" axis. Is there a similar mechanism
in Eigen::Tensor::contract, which allows avoid summation over repeated index?